# Where can I find a standards-compliant C compiler for Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I'm looking for a good, free C compiler for Windows. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are plenty. [Borland C++ Builder](http://www.codegear.com/downloads/free/cppbuilder), [GCC](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/) (on Windows, often used in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)), [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/), [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/), and [LCC-Win32](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/).

I've used GCC (through Linux and Cygwin). I used DJGPP years ago (it was/is a fork of GCC, don't know how close it has stayed) which worked very well. No experience with the rest, really.

Edit: and [MingGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which was already mentioned and may be your best bet if you don't want Cygwin.

Answer (score 14):

Tiny C Compiler

http://bellard.org/tcc/

Its about 200kb. Compiles 9x faster than GCC. No install, just unzip and go.

It doesn't optimize, but it should be fine for learning K&R

Answer (score 7):

[Visual Studio 2008 express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/), if you don't mind Microsoft products, is free, and has C++ support (so, therefore, C support).

Comment: If you want the only compiler that "just works" out of the box, VS Express edition is you only true choice.

Answer (score 6):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) provides recent versions of `gcc` and friends.

Note that recent versions of Visual Studio have much better C standard compatibility. The [Community Edition license](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt171547/) specifies that

> If you are an individual working on your own applications to sell or for any other purpose, you may use the software to develop and test those applications.

You can download [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/).

Answer (score 3):

**[Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/)** is a nice, lightweight IDE for Windows, which bundles an LCC-based compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This mingw link is better and latest.

http://tdragon.net/recentgcc/

Comment: Agreed. The main mingw seems to have stagnated. I hope it doesn't die.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) is an open source C / C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

[Digital Mars C and C++ compilers](http://www.digitalmars.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I use gcc compiler and netbeans IDE. It works fine for me.
Note : Old borland c++ compiler no longer supports win 7 and latest versions which do support win 7 are not free to use. Also if you are not familiar with visual studio environment its best not to opt for Visual Studio Express Edition for writing C programs.